# Processing multiple logs from the same machine using ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk, elastic-beats

I have a single host containing multiple log files. 2 such log files are csab and oneapplogs.

The corrseponding Groks are

**opeapplog :**

```
match => {"message" => "\[%{WORD:fixed}\|%{DATA:time}\|%{WORD:word1}\|%{WORD:word2}\|%{WORD:num1}\|%{WORD:num2}\|%{WORD:loglevel}\|%{WORD:num3}\]%{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
```

**csab :**

```
match => {"message" => "\[%{NONNEGINT:fixed}\|%{DATA:time}\|%{WORD:word1}\|%{NONNEGINT:num1}\|%{NONNEGINT:num2}]\[%{USERNAME:word2}\:%{NONNEGINT:num3}\] %{WORD:word1} : %{USERNAME:fixed} = %{NONNEGINT:num5}"}
```

When I try to send both to Elasticsearch through logstash, being different logs, I have 2 separate logstash conf files for both with different ports for input from filebeats.

I am not able to run the different filebeats at the same. I've read that to do so, I will need to configure completely independent filebeat instances in the machine but I have over 60 logs so setting up 60 instances seems challenging.

Is there any way to send all the files through 1 filebeats instance to logstash and then use logstash to process all logs into multiple different outputs for elasticsearch.

## Simpler explanation

I have 2 logs in the same machine. I need to process them using ELK

I have configured one logstash service having two pipelines, both pipelines separate ports are given. Let's say Pipeline1 (Port 5044) , Pipeline2 (Port 5045)

Now i want to send data to the logstash using filebeat. So i have two types of log file let's say log1, log2.

I want to send log1 to Pipeline1 and log2 to Pipeline 2.

Is this possible with just 1 filebeats instance.

Or is there some other workaround for processing different logs from the same host?

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t understand why you need separate configurations for two sources when you can achieve all these in one configuration file.

Taking the scenario when you have two sources In the system to read log from and you set two different sources in one filebeat configuration only.

```
Output{
If source ~=‘/file/path/for/first/log’
Elasticsearch {
..
..
}
else If source ~=‘/file/path/for/second/log’
Elasticsearch {
..
..
}
}
```